# Invoking a member method pointer from another method

Tags: c++, function-pointers

In `class Foo` I have two methods, `assign_handler()` and `call_handler()`.

The actual handler code is in the `main.cpp` which is `do_this()`. `do_this()` uses the some global variables in `main.cpp`,

I think Foo has to have a function pointer as member which will be assigned in `assign_handler()` which is what I did. However I'm having trouble invoking `assign_handler()` i.e. calling `do_this()`, from `call_handler()`.

Note: `call_handler()` itself is call by a `sigaction` in `Foo`.

EDIT: I tried producing a MCVE as suggested in the comments. I've used gedit to create the files and compile it using g++ in command line. The code works. However in my Eclipse project I get the errors shown in inline comments of the code.

MCVE:

```
//Foo.h
class Foo{
public:
    void (*funptr)(void);
    void call_handler();
    void assign_handler (void(*func1)(void));
    Foo(){};

};
//Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
void Foo::assign_handler(void(*func1)(void)){
    funptr = func1;
}
void Foo::call_handler(){
    funptr();//error: invalid use of member Foo::funptr in static member function; from this location
    //or
    //this->funptr();//error: 'this' is unavailable for static member functions
}
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"
using namespace std;
void do_this(void);
int main(void){
    Foo foo;
    foo.assign_handler(do_this);

    foo.call_handler(); //this won't be called explicitly, it is assigned as a handler for a sigaction
    int x;
    cin>>x;
}

void do_this(void){
    cout<<"done"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code

Comment: I'm assuming that `call_handler` is a static member function, not a regular member as in your example?

Comment: @villintehaspam I just realized I left the static keyword in the class definition. Removing the keyword eliminates the error. I will look into the significance of the static keyword in my code before neglecting it. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are going to call it as a signal handler, it must be static.

Comment: @villintehaspam Noted. Also I've made the implementation more straight forward, and less sexier than I initially intended.

Answer (score 2):

I'll divide my answer in two parts. First I'll attempt to answer your question, then I'll attempt to tell you what you actually want to do.

Your question is how to assign a function pointer to a member variable and then call it from a static member function. Since the function pointer is a member of the class you will also require a pointer to the class in order to call the function pointer. A way of achieving this is to add a static member to your class that holds a pointer to the (single) instance of your class. Since you indicated that you will be using this as a signal handler, you won't want to use multiple handlers anyway.

So, something like this:

```
//Foo.h
class Foo{
public:
    static void call_handler();
    void assign_handler (void(*func1)(void));

    Foo() {    
       ms_instance = this;
    };

private:
    void (*funptr)(void);
    static Foo *ms_instance;
};

//Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
void Foo::assign_handler(void(*func1)(void)){
    funptr = func1;
}
void Foo::call_handler(){
    ms_instance->funptr();
}
```

A more general way would be to store a function object:

```
//Foo.h
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

class Foo{
public:
    static void call_handler();

    template<typename func>
    void assign_handler (func&& handler)
    {
        m_handler = std::forward(handler);
    }

    Foo() {
       ms_instance = this;
    };

private:
    std::function<void(void)> m_handler;
    static Foo *ms_instance;
};

//Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"

void Foo::call_handler(){
    ms_instance->m_handler();
}
```

This way you can assign lots of different stuff as the handler:

```
// Function pointers
foo.assign_handler(do_this);

// Lambdas
foo.assign_handler([]() { /* do something */ });

// Binds - you should probably prefer lambdas...
foo.assign_handler(std::bind(&MyClass::member_func, &myObj));
```

Now what you *actually* want to do when you are going to handle a signal is a bit more complicated. Remember that signal handlers can only call certain functions ([async-signal-safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)) - otherwise things may get ugly. Therefore there is a common trick that you should perform called the self pipe trick. Essentially you should have a signal handler that receives the signal, but only calls `write` on a pipe with the signal number as the data to send. Then you have another place in your code that calls `select` on the pipe and then `read` to read the signal number. You then call the appropriate handler function which is then allowed to do whatever you like.

An example of this is here: http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/altio/self_pipe.c.html

Be aware that it can be slightly tricky to get this right in a cross-platform manner, especially if multithreaded.